# How can I add items array by user on python

Tags: python, arrays, class

I'm learning python but I'm not good at and I didn't find enough information about the class structure.
İ want to add items array by the user but I didn't it. can you help me?

```
class Student():
      def __init__(self, no,name,departmant):
        self.no=no
        self.name=name
        self.departmant=departmant

      def add(self):       
       array = []
        n = int(input('number of students to add: '))
        for i in range(n):  
            enter= print("no:",self.no,"name:",self.name,"departmant:",self.departmant)
            array.append(enter)
            print(array)

      def exit(self):
        print("exit...")
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    no=print("enter students no ")
    namee=print("enter students name :")
    depart=print("enter students departman : ")
    studentt=Student(no,namee,depart)
    studentt.add()
```

Comment: Your code is a bit strange: in one place you have code which reads input from the user in a more or less correct way, but in other places you have totally different code which is broken but should also take input from the user.  Do you see which is which?

Comment: I wanted to write a code that adds a student by the user but 
When I call the insert function from the student class, the data entry does not take the empty array

Comment: Do you want the self.no, self.name and self.departmant all join in one item in the list? Or do you want a list within a list holding each of those things separately?

Comment: You're clearly mixing the things you're trying to do. Please try to define, in readable English, what it is you're trying to do, so we can guide you to your goal.

Comment: im so sorry my english not good if i can said wrong something ,i apologize for you.

Comment: yes, i can self.no, self,name, self,departmant all join one item in the list . but i cant add the list

Answer (score 0):

You are learning i don't want to spoil you but the first point if that you have to devide the logic of the program. If you want to mantain one array which has more than one "student" maybe you should add other class named as Class ListStudents where you have a constructor where you have an array(list in python) of students or Class StudentClass. That was the first point that i wanted to remark. The second one if you want to use the same class maybe you could use the same method add but as static method where you have one list which is in this case is "array" local variables and you only have to call input() inside the foor loop por all variables that you have to modified. Let me show you one example:

```
@classmethod
def the_static_add():
   array = []
   n = int(input("member of students to add"))
   for i in range(n):
       print("Enter the value of no")
       self.no = input()
       print("Enter the value of name")
       self.name = input()
       print("Enter the value of department")
       self.department = input()
       tupleValues = (self.no, self.name, self.department)
       print("no:",self.no,"name:",self.name,"departmant:",self.departmant)
       array.apend(tupleValues)
   return array;
```

I have to note that i have  not used values string in a tuple because is inconsistent, i don't recomend you use this kind of inputs in a tuple, you have to divide logical thinks as much possible.
I hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self, no, name, departmant):
        self.no = no
        self.name = name
        self.departmant = departmant
        self.inputMessage = {
            self.no: 'student number to add: ',
            self.name: 'name of student to add: ',
            self.departmant: 'name of departmant to add: '
        }
        self.studentList = []

    def add(self):
        studentDict = {}
        for key, value in self.inputMessage.items():
            userInput = input(value)
            if key == self.no:
                userInput = int(userInput)
            studentDict[key] = userInput

        self.studentList.append(studentDict)

    def show_students(self):
        for student in self.studentList:
            print("{}: {}".format(self.no, student[self.no]))
            print("{}: {}".format(self.name, student[self.name]))
            print("{}: {}".format(self.departmant, student[self.departmant]))

    def exit(self):
        print("exit...")
        sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    studentClass = Student("no", "name", "departmant")
    studentClass.add()
    print("Result:")
    studentClass.show_students()
```

When you put variable in your class `__init__` don't forget to add them when you instantiate your class.

Instantiate your class first.

Then call the add method. The add method is going to iterate through a dictionary that contains the name of the entry and the input sentence that you want to display. Thus it will have you fill all threee values. You'd better add your students into a list this way you can use the `add` method more than once and create a repository of students.

Finally, I added a `show_student` so that you can see the result you will obtain.

Comment: thank you so much.. So, when i want remove the item ,self.studentList.remove(studentDict)  is it true

Comment: If you want to remove an item, from `self.studentList` you can either remove it by index: `self.studentList.pop(index)` or using one of the key of the `studentDict`. If you prefer the second option, you need to create a method with a `for` loop in it and a `if` clause.

Comment: i want to create function.def remove(self):
          studentDict = {}
          for key, value in self.inputMessage.items():
            userInput = input(value)
            if key == self.no:
                userInput = int(userInput)
            studentDict[key] = userInput

      
            self.studentList.pop(studentDict)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of errors that you need to correct first. I'm listing them for you here:
**IndentationError**: At the third line in add function.

**Import**: in order to use **sys** you need to first import it.

**Entries**: In order to get entries inside loop you need to ask for input inside the loop only.

**Print**: You are assigning print statement to *enter* variable which doesn't makes any sense. Further you are trying to append *enter* to array which is again of no use since *enter* is empty.

Exit: You are using an exit function to print *Exit...* only. You can do that inside the add function itself after the loop.

I've made some gentle changes with comments in your code. I hope it works for you.

Good Luck Pythoning!

Tf this helps you don't forget to upvote.

```
class Student():
    def add(self):
        array = []
        n = int(input('Enter the number of students to add: '))

        # Your previous input is the number of students you want to add so
        # the inputs of user that you want to take should be inside the loop
        # Only then you will be able to add them in repetitive manner.

        # Then we save the values in array named 'values' here to append in array
        # later. Thus you can save an array of details i.e. values inside an array
        # i.e. array.

        # We have used i+1 to print because in range values start from 0 & not 1.

        for i in range(n):
            no = int(input('Enter the no: '))
            name = input('Enter the name: ')
            department = input('Enter the department: ')

            values = [no, name, department]
            print("\n",i+1,"th entry:","no:",no ,"name:",name, "department:",department)
            array.append(values)
            print(array)

        print('\nExit...')

      # There is no point in calling an exit method as far as I see. But if you 
      # want to print 'exit..' then you can print it inside the add function itself
      # outside the loop after getting your entries.

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # There is no point in printing the sentences asking for no, name & department here
    # You are asking them inside the loop when you actually need them.

    studentt=Student()
    studentt.add()
```

Comment: thank you and when i want remove  self.studentList.remove(studentDict) is it true